# Create Date Countdown Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date, powerpoint

I am creating a VBA program in powerpoint to countdown the days until shipping date. (To run on screens in a plant) I am familiar with VBA for Excel but not with powerpoint. I have the start of the code but I need help with looping it continously and having a timer for each slide.Thanks!

*EDIT*

This is what I have so far!
[image]

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Sets variables
 Dim Sdate As Long
 Dim thedate As Date
 Dim txt As Date
 Dim pptSlide3 As PowerPoint.Slide
 Set sld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide

 For Each pptSlide3 In ActivePresentation

 'Retrieves D-Day from text box shown above

  TextBox2.Font.Size = 12
  thedate = TextBox2.Text

  'Calculates the amount of time from today's date until D-day above
  Sdate = DateDiff("d", Now(), thedate)

  'Creates textbox with the value of how many days are left
  TextBox1.Value = Sdate & "  Days to go!"
  TextBox1.Font.Size = 36

  'Want it to wait 5 seconds here
  ' Goes to next slide

   With SlideShowWindows(1).View
   .GotoSlide (sld.SlideIndex + 1)
    End With
'I also want the slideshow to loop continuously, do this for every slide and then loop through them again until the user exits powerpoint
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, where and how do you want to the countdown to be displayed? when you activate the slide for instance. Where is the shipping date read from?

Comment: @Jeanno I would like each slide to have a different date (different ship dates for every project) The slideshow will run on a continuous loop updating continuously.. I know I can put in timers to view the next slide and update... I think I have the start of the code above but I would like it to be automatic :)

Comment: I assume this didn't help. Why? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/how-do-i-make-a-vba-count-down-timer-for/928b07db-e3cb-49c1-aadf-7ce56dedded2?auth=1